# Vagrant no inicia y pasa al estado gurumeditation

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, virtualización

He visto que preguntaron sobre esto en el Stack Overflow en inglés y lo pregunto acá, porque allá no logré obtener solución, al momento de iniciar vagrant con `vagrant up`, éste no inicia y recibo el siguiente mensaje:

> ==> homestead-7: Forcing shutdown of VM...
>
> ==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
>
> ==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
>
> ==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>
> ==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
>
> homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
>
> homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
>
> ==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
>
> homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
>
> homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
>
> homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
>
> homestead-7: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
>
> homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
>
> homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
>
> homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
>
> homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
>
> ==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
>
> ==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
>
> ==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
>
> homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
>
> homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
>
> homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
>
> The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it to
>   boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
>   'gurumeditation' state. Please verify everything is configured
>   properly and try again.
>
> If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it, it is often
>   helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the GUI often has
>   more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve. For example, if
>   you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the VirtualBox GUI is
>   open.
>
> The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using is
>   not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.

He intentado lo que han dicho por ahí, sobre meterme en la bios y activar `intel virtualization tech` y nada, me metí en características de programas y no me aparece `l Vt-x`, ¿alguien sabe cómo solucionar dicho problema? Ya que sin esto no puedo empezar a correr con Laravel.

Comment: si no aparece lo de virtualizacion en tu bios entonces no puedes virtualizar, trata de buscar (si es que sabes que tiene virtualizador tu pc) por el modelo de tu pc para poder activarlo o de lo contrario no puedes usarlo, asi es como funciona necesitas si o si virtualizador acitivado en la bios.

Comment: Si, si lo tiene, incluso ya lo tenia activado, en la bios aparece como Intel virtualization tech, y lo deje activado y sigue igual